# In Fullmetal Alchemist, how do the Elric brothers create things seemingly without equal loss?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist

There's plenty of times when there is clear source material such as when Edward turns the tower into flowers during his exam. However, it seems like Edward often creates things without putting in any material for exchange. Toward the beginning of the season he generates a cage to stop a thief. Was the source material the ground and thus there's a big hole underground? I can't think of other examples off the top of my head, but I've seen plenty with no seeming source material. Are they trading atmospheric gas which is why no source material is visible?

Also, can alchemists remove things without the need of equal exchange? Towards the end of the episode with the red water (episode 1x12) Edward makes a wall disappear in the mine. Did he relocate it, turn it into gas, or did it get removed without equal gain? He then puts the wall back in place seemingly from thin air when a canon of sorts was shot at him.

Answer (score 6):

Despite the name, it seems that the "transmutation" of *Fullmetal Alchemist* is not capable of [actual transmutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_transmutation). We know this from the first episode, in which Edward lists off the elements making up a human body, to prove a point to Rose. He needed those elements, in those quantities, to attempt the transmutation of his mother. So the "atmospheric gas" explanation is likely not correct. You can't make a reasonable solid object out of [(mostly) nitrogen and oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Earth#Composition), without a substantial supply of carbon or another element to hold it all together. Additionally, the density of atmospheric gas is far too low to make anything of an interesting mass.

Therefore, the more plausible theory is that, whenever we see Alphonse or Edward producing objects out of the ground, they are building it out of the surrounding rock or dirt. In some episodes, we can clearly see depressions or voids on the surface, showing where this material is coming from. As I recall, this is more consistently shown in *Brotherhood* and in the manga than in the 2003 anime. However, provided the surrounding earth is stable enough, there is no obvious reason they could not create an underground void instead of a surface void, so there need not be visual evidence of equivalent exchange.

Comment: I think I remember a couple exceptions, but your answer is still good, so thank you.

Comment: As a more concrete example, the staff weapons that Ed and his teacher sometimes create leave shallow dimples in the ground to account for the material taken to make the staff.

Comment: Actually, while there is a limit, they can do actual transmutation. Toward the end of the series, it is mentioned that the turning things into gold is forbidden by the government, which implies that it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

To what I recall, you need a circle with that ever specific signs to manipulate a certin element or something like that. When Ed and Al have their mother incident, the Gate of Truth takes something of them,  and in exchange they can manipulate without the circle. Yet again,  only people that try to bring people back to life [or another taboo? ] have been able to see the gate of truth, I really don't recall how it goes,  but if you see the gate of truth and survive,  you don't need the circle for equivalent exchange. The circle is like everyone's personal gate of truth in the world they live in without needing to sacrifice a part of you,  but when you see the real one if live you already have it inside them. 
That's the vest I can explain why Ed and Al can do all that without any circle of materials to use as exchange.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Your answer deals more with the methods of transmutation whereas the question asks about the material requirements.

Comment: That said, once you see the gate of truth, you make a sacrifice (Ed's leg for mom, arm for brother, Al's body, others examples are spoilers) then you basically get a Matrix-style download of the art/science of alchemy, part of which includes the circle-less transmutations. Though the rules aren't really in stone as Al didn't remember the same as Ed at first.

Comment: Is more like to be able to see the gate gives them the power to make anything with out all the materials needed or manipulate other elements and turn them into other elements.  I think it also depends of which FMA series we are talking about, the first one or brotherhood. The first series has too many loop holes. This link will help you undertand better how they can do it without the presence of other materials. https://www.quora.com/How-is-it-that-Edward-Elric-can-perform-alchemy-without-drawing-transmutation-circles